# Having a url as a parameter of a GET request

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

For my node application I need a user to be able to pass a url as a parameter in a get request.

I have tried having the url as a parameter after '?' but it still seems to not work.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get("/create/:id")
```

This is the code (minus the callback) that I am using and what should happen is the parameter id should become "google.com/images" if the url is "example.com/create/google.com/images" but instead the route isn't called.

Comment: Have a look at https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters. Typically though you'd URL-encode the parameter to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Form a request like this

[http://localhost:3006/create/2?q=https://twitter.com/]

In the above url id => 2, q => https://twitter.com

In req.query you will get `{"q":"https://twitter.com/"}`.